# Skip certain number of lines while reading a text file - BufferedReader Java

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I have several files in a directory that I intend to skip a certain number of lines. The only way to get the lines to skip is to get the first occurrence of  a line that has a character length of 1. The only available information is that the line occurs anywhere before line number 60. So I have written the following method to attempt to skip the lines before the character. But I end up getting the same file as the original file:

```
public static void editSplitFiles(File sourceDir) {
    FilenameFilter only = new OnlyExt("RPT");
    log.debug("Editing Split Files........");
    String[] filenames = sourceDir.list(only);
    try {
        for (int k = 0; k < filenames.length; k++) {
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + filenames[k]);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + filenames[k] + ".LST");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
            String strLine;
            int num = 0;
            int splitLine = 0;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                num++;
                if (strLine.length() == 1) {
                    splitLine = num;
                }

                bw.write(strLine);
                bw.newLine();
                bw.flush();
            }
            if (splitLine < 60) {
                log.debug("File Name" + filenames[k] + "Line Number - " + splitLine);//This gives me the correct line number where the character is for each file.
                br.readLine();
            }

            fs.close();
            br.close();
            fos.close();
            bw.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception asd) {
        log.debug(asd.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but it looks like the file is getting written before I skip. How do I accomplish this?

**EDIT**
The files looks like this:
[image: Sample File]

Comment: do you have an example of a file and whats the expected output?

Comment: It is a bit unclear, are you looking for a line of size 1 (like your code seems to do), or the character `1` ?

Comment: You are evaluating `strLine.length() == 1` but regardless of tthat you're going to `bw.write(strLine)`. As long as `splitLine < 60` you read an additional line. The output should have every second line until line 60 and then every line from the file you read. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @LuCio I am trying to avoid a situation where condition `strLine.length() == 1` becomes true in other lines which are greater than 60

Comment: @Arnaud The first occurence of a line of length 1 is where I am supposed to skip up to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out by storing the lines to skip value for each file in a Map. Then iterate through the map and skip the number of lines for each file. I thought there should be an easy way to it.

```
public static Map getSplitMap(File sourceDir) {
        FilenameFilter only = new OnlyExt("RPT");
        log.debug("Getting split Map........");
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
        String[] filenames = sourceDir.list(only);
        try {
            for (int k = 0; k < filenames.length; k++) {
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + filenames[k]);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

                String strLine;
                int num = 0;
                int splitLine = 0;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    num++;
                    if (strLine.length() == 1) {
                        splitLine = num;

                    }
                    if (splitLine < 60) {
                        map.put(filenames[k], splitLine);
                    }
                }

                fs.close();
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Then Skip the lines per file:

```
 public static void splitFile(File sourceDir) {
        Map<String, Integer> map = getSplitMap(sourceDir);
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + entry.getKey());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + entry.getKey() + ".LST");
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
                for (int i = 1; i < entry.getValue(); i++) {
                    br.readLine();
                }
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    bw.write(strLine);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.flush();
                }
                fs.close();
                br.close();
                fos.close();
                bw.close();
                File files = new File(sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + entry.getKey());
                files.delete();
            }
        } catch (Exception asd) {
            log.debug(asd.getMessage());
        }
    }
```